# How to make text appear in a single line in RadioListTile

Tags: flutter

I'm new to learning flutter and am learning about radio list tiles. I have made an app that contains two tiles and a text widget in a row. The problem is that the title of the tile takes up two lines as its a bit longer instead of one. Here's the problem I'm talking about:

[image]

Code to reproduce the problem:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
            height: 75,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              color: const Color.fromARGB(48, 101, 103, 126),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  const Text('Gender:'),
                  Expanded(
                    child: RadioListTile(
                      value: 'Female',
                      title: const Text('Female'),
                      groupValue: 'Female',
                      onChanged: (value) {},
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: RadioListTile(
                      value: 'Male',
                      title: const Text('Male'),
                      groupValue: 'Female',
                      onChanged: (value) {},
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The parent of this widget is: scaffold -> material app.

Is there any way to fix it without decreasing the fontSize?

I am running the code on simulator.

Comment: One way to force text to appear in one line is by wrapping it in `FittedBox`

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding contentPadding parameter to the list tile. By default it is set to 16 pixels symmetric horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

**To fix the issue of the title in the RadioListTile taking up two lines, you can wrap the Text widget with a Flexible widget and set its overflow property to TextOverflow.ellipsis.**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
            height: 75,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              color: const Color.fromARGB(48, 101, 103, 126),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  const Text('Gender:'),
                  Expanded(
                    child: RadioListTile(
                      value: 'Female',
                      title: Flexible(
                        child: Text(
                          'Female',
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        ),
                      ),
                      groupValue: 'Female',
                      onChanged: (value) {},
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: RadioListTile(
                      value: 'Male',
                      title: Flexible(
                        child: Text(
                          'Male',
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        ),
                      ),
                      groupValue: 'Female',
                      onChanged: (value) {},
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```